# Java Package Error while compiling the following code

Tags: java

Hi I ve created the following code and the first file called "Draggable.java" is compiled. and the second file "Circle.java" shows me an error.... Please aneswer

In the Draggable.java file

```
package graphics;

public interface Draggable {

}
```

In the Circle.java file

```
package graphics;

public class Circle implements Draggable {

}
```

Note: I ve put the above files in a folder called "graphics".

Comment: What is the complete error message ?

Comment: And how do you compile it? My guess is that you are compiling from inside the graphics directory, that will probably not work as you expect. Move to the parent directory and give the whole path to the class on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

If your error is:

```
Circle.java:3: cannot find symbol
symbol: class Draggable
public class Circle implements Draggable {
                               ^
1 error
```

then you need to add the classpath to your `javac` command (assuming you are in the `graphics` directory):

```
javac -cp .. Circle.java
```

Ideally though, you would compile from the project root (the parent folder of `graphics`) and do this to compile:

```
javac graphics/*.java
```

or

```
javac graphics/Draggable.java
// followed by
javac graphics/Circle.java
```

Comment: That's wrong, though; the classpath would need to be the current directory, `"."` The classpath is the *root* of the package hierarchy, not a specific package within it.

Comment: Sorry, went too fast on the answer. Long time didn't use an IDE :)